# Limit duration of DAX queries

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a few users sometimes executing highly imperformant DAX queries against an OnPrem SSAS Tabular database.

Is there are server side setting to limit the duration of queries so that the server cancels long running queries automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the [ServerTimeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/server-properties/general-properties?).